# Different getter methods for returning instance vs. instance variable based on position in dot notation?

Tags: python, oop, properties, polymorphism, getter-setter

Is there a way to implement two different getter methods in Python, i.e. one that returns an instance and one that returns the instance attribute (depending on where the getter is called in dot notation)?

My use case is a class that can generate new instances of this class recursively. These new instances are other representations of the initial value `init_val`. Each of these representations can again create an instance of this class. So in the end, each representation has arbitrary levels of other representations.

A short minimal example:

```python
from <...> import conversion_function_1, conversion_function_2, conversion_function_3


class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, value):
    # avoid infinite recursion for self.alt_rep_<1/2/3>
    if not (value is None):
      self._value = value
      
      # alternative representations of <self.value>
      self._alt_rep_1 = SomeClass(value=None)
      self._alt_rep_2 = SomeClass(value=None)
      self._alt_rep_3 = SomeClass(value=None)


  @property
  def value(self):
    return self._value

  @property
  def alt_rep_1(self):
    return self._alt_rep_1

  @property
  def alt_rep_2(self):
    return self._alt_rep_2

  @property
  def alt_rep_3(self):
    return self._alt_rep_3


  def convert_to_rep_1(self):
    self._alt_rep_1 = conversion_function_1(self.value)

  def convert_to_rep_2(self):
    self._alt_rep_2 = conversion_function_2(self.value)

  def convert_to_rep_3(self):
    self._alt_rep_3 = conversion_function_3(self.value)



''' MAIN ROUTINE '''
if __name__ == '__main__':
  value = <...>
  example = SomeClass(init_val=value)
  
  # create different representations
  example.convert_to_rep_1()
  example.convert_to_rep_2()
  example.convert_to_rep_3()

  # continue with creating different representations recursicely
  example.alt_rep_1.convert_to_rep_2()
  example.alt_rep_1.convert_to_rep_3()

  example.alt_rep_2.convert_to_rep_1()
  example.alt_rep_2.convert_to_rep_3()

  < ... >


  # now I want to print the value of different representations, which can be found in variable <value>.
  print(example.alt_rep_1.value)
  print(example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.value)
  print(example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_3.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_1.value)
```

Now I would like to omit the last `.value`, since it is redundant. So if an object is the last object in dot notation, I want to return `self.value`, but otherwise I need to return the object  `self`, because I want to access other objects down the recursive hierarchy.

So I need something like, where I am not sure how to fill <???>:

```python
@property
def value(self):
  if (<???>):
    return self._value
  else:
    return self
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you set the three `_alt_rep`to `None` in the `__init__`? Then your condition inside the `value` method could be just checking all `_alt_rep`attributes are `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, @JorgeLuis! I discarded this for 2 reasons:
(1) - different representations (e.g. ``example.alt_rep1``, ``example.alt_rep3``, ...) can be set, but I still want to access the original value (``example.value``) instead of the object. Checking for None will not allow this.
(2) - it might be that I set a an alternative representation of a "deeper" property first, but then want to infer an "upper" property (e.g. infer ``example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2`` from ``example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.alt_rep3``).

Comment: Do you expect `value` to be always of the same type?

Comment: What is the returning type of `conversion_function_1`? Is it `SomeClass`? Because otherwise `convert_to_rep_1` I guess should be `self._alt_rep_1.value = conversion_function_1(self.value)`

Comment: The return type is ``SomeClass``, yes.
Unfortunately, ``value`` is not always the same type. But it is always either an ``ndarray`` (with different numerical types, and possibly dimensions) or a list.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask sounds similar to the [decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator).
Let's take take advantage on the fact that Python allows us to add new attributes to a new object. So let's create a new object of `ndarray` or `list` and add the attributes and methods that you need. This way you can get rid of `value`.
That's all. To hide everything up lets make some classes:

```
import numpy as np


class SomeClassBase:
    def __init__(self, value):
        # avoid infinite recursion for self.alt_rep_<1/2/3>
        if value is not None:

            # alternative representations of <self.value>
            self._alt_rep_1 = SomeClass(value=None)
            self._alt_rep_2 = SomeClass(value=None)
            self._alt_rep_3 = SomeClass(value=None)

    # Your methods, but delete value
    ...


class SomeClassList(list, SomeClassBase):
    def __new__(cls, value: list):
        # Create a new list object
        instance = list.__new__(cls, [])
        instance += value
        SomeClassBase.__init__(instance, value)
        return instance


class SomeClassNp(np.ndarray, SomeClassBase):
    def __new__(cls, value: np.ndarray):
        # Create a new array object
        obj = np.asarray(value).view(cls)
        SomeClassBase.__init__(obj, value)
        return obj

# Interface to hide all the other classes
class SomeClass:
    # Return an object attending to the argument
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if type(value) == list:
            return SomeClassList(value)
        if type(value) == np.ndarray:
            return SomeClassNp(value)
        return SomeClassBase(None)


# Trivial methods to let the code run
def conversion_function_1(v: SomeClass) -> SomeClass:
    return v
def conversion_function_2(v: SomeClass) -> SomeClass:
    return v
def conversion_function_3(v: SomeClass) -> SomeClass:
    return v


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Works for both cases
    value = [12]
    value = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')
    example = SomeClass(value)

    # create different representations
    example.convert_to_rep_1()
    example.alt_rep_1.convert_to_rep_2()
    example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.convert_to_rep_3()
    example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_3.convert_to_rep_2()
    example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_3.alt_rep_2.convert_to_rep_1()

    # Print the values
    print(example.alt_rep_1)
    print(example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2)
    print(example.alt_rep_1.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_3.alt_rep_2.alt_rep_1)
```

Don't panic. The classes `SomeClassList` and `SomeClassNp` just create a new instance to add your methods to.

Depending on your needs you might need to look inheritances with a little more care.

Comment: Thanks for your input - the Decorator is a good idea! I will try it out!